# recovery media help for windows 8.1 Toshiba c55d-b5102

Tags: windows, boot, toshiba-laptop

i have a windows 8.1 toshiba satellite c55d-b5102 and it has already been wiped. but when starting it, it asked for me to select boot media from list below. however, there isn't anything for me to select. what do i do? i've gone to toshiba recovery page to download recovery media but im not sure which one to download.

Answer (score 0):

Install Linux.

If the drive has been wiped, and you don't have the original installation or rescue media, you won't have a Windows license. For that matter, if enough damage was done by the wipe process, you might not be able to install an OS in UEFI mode, if that is available on that machine.

You can install a Linux distro, such as [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0), from a "live" USB flash drive or from a CD/DVD. You can run from the external media without installing to HDD to see if you like it.